# Tangents to $y=ax^2+bx+c$ from roots

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let $y=ax^2+bx+c$  be a parabola and roots of parabola be $x_1,x_2$.
Show that If the tangents drawn from the points where the parabola intersects the $x$-axis are perpendicular to each other, the discriminant of the parabola equation is $1$.

My solution is below:

Product of slope of tangents must be $-1$ . $$-1=(2ax_1+b)(2ax_2+b)=b^2+2ab(x_1+x_2)+4a^2(x_1x_2)=b^2+2ab(-\frac{b}{a})+4a^2(\frac ca)=4ac-b^2=-\Delta.$$

But I use derivative of $y=ax^2+bx+c$. But I am looking for not using derivative.

Comment: I not sure if it is possible to find the slop of the tangent of a parabola without using derivative (explicitly or implicitly). Maybe it is possible to prove this result using the reflection properties of the parabola, but, again, I could not find any proof of those those properties that are not based in derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that solving a line that is tangent with the parabola will have only one solution, which will also be the point of contact.

Let $y = mx + c_t$ be the tangent line, where $m$ is the slope of this line. Solving with the equation of parabola gives us:

$$mx + c_t = ax^2 + bx +c$$

$$\Rightarrow ax^2 + \left(b-m\right)x +c-c_t = 0$$

Since this is a quadratic equation, it has two roots, but since there is only one solution, the root is repeated. It means that the discriminant of the quadratic equation is $0$.

Let the point of contact be $\left(x_0, y_0\right)$.

$$\Rightarrow x_0 = -\frac{b-m}{2a}$$
$$\Rightarrow m = 2ax_0+b$$

Now, you know the slope of the tangent of a parabola to any point without using derivatives.